# Analogue of break and continue in java stream api?

Tags: java, java-stream

1. Is it possible to interrupt the execution of a thread (stream api) by analogy
   with **break**?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i == 4) {
    break;
  }
}
```

2. Is it possible to skip a flow element like **continue**?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i == 4) {
    continue;
  }
}
```

Maybe use `takeWhile` or `filter`?

Comment: From which places? Can you give some equivalent code that you'd like to represent?

Comment: Short answer - no. But there are other stream constructs like *filter*, *findFirst*, *findAny* etc, that you could use depending on what you are doing.

Comment: You can sort-of emulate `continue` with a `map` that returns an Optional: return an `empty` if you want to "continue", and a present otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different cases where `break` and `continue` could be used in a for-loop. There are a few cases with replacement with stream API.

### Breaking the loop on invalid item

Break is used at the beginning of for-loop in this case to stop loop when finding some item with predicate.

Starting from Java-9 you can use `takeWhile` method which is logically similar to `break` on condition in for loop: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)

E.g. this code:

```java
for (String item : list) {
  if (item.isEmpty()) {
    break;
  }
  processItem(item);
}
```

Could be changed to stream version as:

```java
list.stream()
  .takeWhile(item -> !item.isEmpty())
  .forEach(item -> processItem(item));
```

Pay attention to this note:

> If this stream is unordered, and some (but not all) elements of this stream match the given predicate, then the behavior of this operation is nondeterministic

### Continue the loop to filter out elements

Continue is used at the beginning of for-loop to filter some items from processing.

For some cases of `continue` you may adopt `filter` stream method: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)

For loop code with `continue`:

```java
for (String item : list) {
  if (item.isEmpty()) {
    continue;
  }
  processItem(item);
}
```

Stream with `filter`:

```java
list.stream()
  .filter(item -> !item.isEmpty())
  .forEach(item -> processItem(item));
```